# How to show a norm satisifies the triangle inequality on an $l_p$ space

Tags: analysis

Define an $l_p$ space to be all sequences $x_n$ in $\mathbb{R}$ s.t.

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_n|^p <\infty$ if $p<\infty$ and $sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}|x_n|<\infty$ if $p=\infty$

Suppose we have the norm $||x||_p=(\sum_{n=1}^\infty|x_n|^p)^{1/p}$ and $||x||_p =sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}|x_n|$ if $p=\infty$

I have been trying to show that this is a norm by checking the triangle inequality but I cannot figure out how to do this. Here is what I have so far:

The goal is to show: $abs(||x||_p - ||y||_p)\leq abs(||x||_p) - abs(||y||_p)$

$abs(||x||_p - ||y||_p)$ $= abs((\sum_{n=1}^\infty|x_n|^p)^{1/p} -(\sum_{n=1}^\infty|y_n|^p)^{1/p})=(\sum_{n=1}^\infty|x_n|^p-|y_n|^p)^{1/p}=(\sum_{n=1}^\infty(|x_n|-|y_n|)^p)^{1/p}$

But now I am stuck. How do I get to the right hand side of what I am trying to show. I feel like any or every part of what I've written could be wrong.

Comment: I'm assuming $p\geq 1$, right? Then it should just be Minkowski's inequality.

Comment: I have that Minkowski's Inequality states: "$\forall x,y \in l_2$ we have that $||x+y||_2\leq||x||_2 + ||y||_2$ This seems to say something different. I'm still confused. Does Minkowski's Inequality apply to $l_p$ ? Also this appears to be adding versus subtracting the norm of the vectors.

Comment: Here's the wiki link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality